# catch error while creating context spring

Tags: spring

I'm trying to control errors during to create the bean's context of Spring, because I need to continue the creation of other beans declared if some bean can't create.

How can I do this?

spring_context.xml

```
<bean id="poolExecutorSpp" . . . </bean> 
<bean id="Queue"> . . . </bean> 
<bean id="datasource"> . . . </bean>
```

If some bean fail creation any bean is created and the context not loaded. I want to continue with the creation other beans if for example fail creation the bean "Queue".

Comment: Little more explanation with code samples would be helpful to answer.

Comment: spring_context.xml
<bean id="poolExecutorSpp" 
.
.
.
</bean>

<bean id="Queue">
.
.
.
</bean>

<bean id="datasource">
.
.
.
</bean>

If some bean fail creation any bean is created and the context not loaded. I want to continue with the creation other beans if for example fail creation the bean "Queue".

Comment: Add the code sample to the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to ignore Exceptions during Spring context initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8326218/how-to-ignore-exceptions-during-spring-context-initialization)